# Displaying Chinese, Korean and Japanese fonts in Chrome and Firefox on Travis CI

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, travis-ci, asianfonts

I'm running visual browser tests in Chrome and Firefox on Travis CI. For this I'm using the [Trusty build environment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/trusty/) (i.e. Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS) and the following addons (from the `.travis.yml`):

```
addons:
  chrome: stable
  firefox: "69.0.1"
  apt:
    packages:
      - chromium-chromedriver
```

Before executing the tests, I also run the following setup script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail

GECKODRIVER_VERSION="v0.24.0"
GECKODRIVER_HASH="7552b85e43973c84763e212af7cca566"

# Chrome

ln --symbolic /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver "${HOME}/bin/chromedriver"

# Firefox

wget --quiet https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/${GECKODRIVER_VERSION}/geckodriver-${GECKODRIVER_VERSION}-linux64.tar.gz
echo ${GECKODRIVER_HASH} "geckodriver-${GECKODRIVER_VERSION}-linux64.tar.gz" | md5sum --check -
tar xf "geckodriver-${GECKODRIVER_VERSION}-linux64.tar.gz" -C ${HOME}/bin/
```

The tests basically run fine, but looking at the screenshots I receive from Travis CI, I realized that Chinese, Korean and Japanese fonts aren't displayed properly (see footer):

[image: screenshot diff]

How can fix this issue, e.g, by installing an Asian fonts package on Travis CI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by [installing Asian fonts](https://help.accusoft.com/PrizmDoc/v12.1/HTML/Installing_Asian_Fonts_on_Ubuntu_and_Debian.html) on Ubuntu, i.e., on OS level. One can do this by adapting the `.travis.yml` as follows:

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      # Japanese
      - language-pack-ja
      - japan*
      # Chinese
      - language-pack-zh*
      - chinese*
      # Korean
      - language-pack-ko
      - korean*
      # Fonts
      - fonts-arphic-ukai
      - fonts-arphic-uming
      - fonts-ipafont-mincho
      - fonts-ipafont-gothic
      - fonts-unfonts-core
```